# Prof of increasing (decreasing) speed when the dot product of velocity and acceleration is positive (negative)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-spaces

Trying to understand following proof: "Show that if the dot product of the velocity and acceleration of a moving particle is positive (or negative), then the speed of the particle is increasing (decreasing)".

That will be the dot-product ($\cdot$) of vector $\vec v(t)$ (velocity) and vector $\vec a(t)$ (acceleration), where $\vec a(t)$ is equal to the derivative ($\frac{d}{dt}$) of vector $\vec v(t)$ ($\frac{d}{dt} \vec v(t) = \vec a(t)$), and the absolute value of the velocity $\vec v(t)=|\vec v(t)|$ is the moving particles speed.

The solution reads:

$ \frac{d}{dt} |\vec v(t)|^2 = \frac{d}{dt} \vec v(t) \cdot \vec v(t) = 2 \vec v(t) \cdot \vec a(t)$

if $\vec v(t) \cdot \vec a(t) > 0$ then $|\vec v(t)|$ is increasing

if $\vec v(t) \cdot \vec a(t) < 0$ then $|\vec v(t)|$ is decreasing

There seems to be something with the notation that I do not quite understand.

When I try myself:

$\vec v(t) \cdot \vec a(t) = \frac{d}{dt} \vec v(t) \cdot \vec v(t) = \frac{d}{dt}(\vec v(t))^2 = 2 \vec v(t) \cdot \vec a(t)$ (Last step according to the chain rule)

Which results in an inequality. If this would be the case then $\vec v(t) \cdot \vec a(t)$ would equal itself times 2 to the power of any natural number.

What is the correlation between $\vec v(t) \cdot \vec v(t)$ and $|\vec v(t)|^2$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: You should probably start liking some of their comments and/or answers,  just imo

Comment: I have tried up-voting the answer, but I do not have enough "reputation". Is there some other way to show gratitude?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for your last question, "What is the correlation between $v(t)\cdot v(t)$ and $|v(t)|^2$", they are exactly the same!  For any vector u, |u| is **defined** as "$\sqrt{u\cdot u}$".  Squaring both sides, $u\cdot u=  |u|^2$.

Now for the main question- you are confusing yourself with poor notation, writing "d/dt v(t)" instead of "dv(t)/dt".  Becaus of that notation, you are writing "d/dt v(t)v(t)= d/dt v^2(t)".  That last step is wrong.

d/dt is being applied to v(t) THEN the result is multiplied by v(t).  v(t) is NOT being multiplie by v(t) and then d/dt applied to the product.  Had you written "(dv(t)/dt)v(t)" or, better, "$\frac{dv(t)}{dt}v(t)$" you would have seen that.

Comment: Thank you for answering! Super helpful!

I assumed that the notation must have been I as mentioned in my solution above, since the solution were supposed to be: 

$\frac{d}{dt}|\vec v(t)|^2=\frac{d}{dt}\vec v(t)\cdot\vec v(t) = 2\vec v(t)\cdot\vec a(t)$

if $\vec v(t)\cdot\vec a(t)>0$ then $|\vec v(t)|$ is increasing

if $\vec v(t)\cdot\vec a(t)<0$ then $|\vec v(t)|$ is decreasing

Comment: I think that I now have figured out why i was struggling with the proof!
Here is where i got stuck: 

$\vec v(t)\cdot\vec a(t)=\vec v(t)\cdot\frac{d{\vec v(t)}}{dt}=|\vec v(t)|\cdot \frac{d{|\vec v(t)|}}{dt}$

if $\vec v(t)\cdot\vec a(t)<0$ then $\frac{d{|\vec v(t)|}}{dt}\\$

(Not sure if $\frac{d{|\vec v(t)|}}{dt} = \frac{d{\vec v(t)}}{dt}$ is ture at all(?))

But why would then $\frac{d{|\vec v(t)|}}{dt}$ prove whether the speed ($|\vec v(t)|$) is increasing/decreasing? It simply does not, right?

Comment: Or:
$\vec v(t)\cdot\vec a(t)=\frac{d}{dt}\vec v(t)\cdot\vec v(t)=\frac{d}{dt}(\vec v(t))^2=2 \vec v(t)\cdot\vec a(t)$ 
Which is incorrect notation!

Comment: The proof includes differentiating the speed squared ($|\vec v(t)|^2$), to refer to a equation that firstly is an expression of the speed which also can be expressed including the dot product of the velocity ($\vec v(t)$) and the acceleration ($\vec a(t)$) which ($ \frac{d}{dt} |\vec v(t)|^2$) is!

Comment: Therefore $ \frac{d}{dt} |\vec v(t)|^2 = \frac{d}{dt} (\vec v(t) \cdot \vec v(t)) = 2 \vec v(t) \cdot \vec a(t)$.
Which proves that if the dot product of the velocity and the acceleration is positive, then the rate of change for the speed must be positive, i.e increasing. The same argument goes for a negative dot product, i.e decreasing.